# add name field in laravel spark update member modal

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-spark

I want to add some extra fields in Spark model form when we click on **edit a member**. Out of the box currently, Spark gives only `role` dropdown, I have added `name` field in this, box but How can save updated name in DB.

I have checked the route and found

`Laravel\Spark\Http\Controllers\Settings\Teams\TeamMemberController@update`

Is handling the update method. This controller delegates updation and validation to this class

`Laravel\Spark\Interactions\Settings\Teams\UpdateTeamMember`

I want to use `Spark::swap()` but It's not working

`Spark::swap('UpdateTeamMember', 'App\Swap\UpdateTeamMember');`

Please help to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

From the Spark FAQ page, in the Cookbook section:

1. Adding Registration Fields - https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/adding-registration-fields
2. Adding Profile Fields - https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/adding-profile-fields